# How to set method, header, parameter in Alamofire 4 and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

In past version of `Alamofire`, for send method,header and parameter I used to do like this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLRequest, headers:headers, parameters: parameters)
```

but version 4 and swift 3 is different.
How can I set method, send header & parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration guide at [Alamofire github](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) explains this very well.

Take a look here:

```
// Alamofire 3
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
    print("Bytes: \(bytesRead), Total Bytes: \(totalBytesRead), Total     Bytes Expected: \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
}
.validate { request, response in
    // Custom evaluation closure (no access to server data)
    return .success
}
.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}

// Alamofire 4
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
.downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.utility) { progress in
    print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
.validate { request, response, data in
    // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
    return .success
}
.responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The migration guide explained well, but there are no headers in the example, just to avoid confusions, bellow I add the example of a GET request to add them.

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    .validate { request, response, data in
        return .success
    }
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            // do something
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            // handle error
            break
        }
    }
```

I found this information in [here](https://grokswift.com/custom-headers-alamofire4-swift3/) so, go and check it there if you have question related with the headers in the request.